# How to remove an element from a Set based on a property value?

Tags: java, oop, collections

I have a static `List<Set<Cards>>` allcards in a class. The card object has 2 variables which are, String suit and int value. I am creating a set of 52 cards and I am initializing a list of 8 such Sets in the above static parameter.

I pick one set from the list and remove one card from the set. Now if I check the list to see if it has been deleted it does not reflect the removal of my card object from the set.

how do I remove a card from my `List<Set<Cards>>` variable such that it reflect those changes when I use the variable elsewhere.

```
public class Test {
  static Shoe shoe = new Shoe();
  static List < Set < Card >> listofdecks;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 0;
    listofdecks = new ArrayList < > (shoe.getDecklist());

    for (Set < Card > cards: listofdecks)
      for (Card c: cards)
        count++;
    System.out.println(count);

    listofdecks.get(0).remove(0);

    count = 0;
    for (Set < Card > cards: listofdecks)
      for (Card c: cards)
        count++;

    System.out.println(count);

  }
}
```

```
public class Shoe {


  private static Deck deck;
  private static List < Set < Card >> decklist;


  public Shoe() {
    setDecklist();
  }
  public static void setDecklist(List < Set < Card >> decklist) {
    Shoe.decklist = decklist;
  }

  public static Deck getDeck() {
    return deck;
  }

  public static void setDeck(Deck deck) {
    Shoe.deck = deck;
  }

  public static List < Set < Card >> getDecklist() {
    return decklist;
  }

  public static void setDecklist() {
    decklist = new ArrayList < > ();
    deck = new Deck();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      decklist.add(Deck.getNewDeck());
  }

}
```

Comment: could you show code?

Comment: I have updated my question with the code. Thanks

Comment: The `Set` interface does not allow you to remove from a numeric index (because a `Set` is not ordered, and so has no indices). Instead the `Set` interface has a `remove(Object)` method which requires you to specify the exact object you want removed from the set.

Comment: you can use  `count += cards.size()` instead of  `for(Card c:cards)
            count++;` could toy also show `shoe.getDecklist()` function?

Comment: If you did not override equals and hashCode methods in Card class then you should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `listofdecks.get(0).remove(0);` is calls `boolean remove(Object o);` from `Set<>` interface. Which meant that you try to remove `Integer` from the set of `Card`s. That's why nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

As dehasi mentioned the remove function of java set takes an object which is to be removed.  Though you cannot remove the object while iterating, but you can remove the object by using  iterator for both list and set.